# Modifying NSDictionary in run Time

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, nsdictionary

Please Help me.

I have a plist clothingList.plist

I am accessing it like this in a method

```
 NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ClothingList" ofType:@"plist"];
 //NSDictionary *ClothingAssets ; //Declared globally in .h file

  ClothingAssets=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:ClothingAssets forKey:@"ClothingAssets"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Now I want to modfify a bool value in Clothing Assets Dictionary in another method.

```
 ClothingAssets=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"ClothingAssets"];
 [[[[[[ClothingAssets objectForKey:@"ClothingStore"] objectAtIndex:temp_Store]objectForKey:@"Assets" ]objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",temp_AssetType]] objectAtIndex:ii] setValue:@"YES" forKey:@"isLock"] ;
```

When I run the code For the first time it crashes and Show an error like this:

```
************ Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'***
 *** First throw call stack:
 (0x1fb5012 0x29c5e7e 0x1fb4deb 0x1f7b347 0x3f39bf 0x435d9 0x41f76 0xea5020 0x29d9705 0xab5920 0xab58b8 0xb76671 0xb76bcf 0xb75d38 0xae533f 0xae5552 0xac33aa 0xab4cf8 0x3397df9 0x3397ad0 0x1f2abf5 0x1f2a962 0x1f5bbb6 0x1f5af44 0x1f5ae1b 0x33967e3 0x3396668 0xab265c 0x22ed 0x2225 0x1)
 libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception******
```

But When I run the code for second time it is working properly.

please help me.

Comment: Blimey six `[` in one statement; nice going.  Do you think that is easy to understand?

Answer (score 2):

There are many similar questions. From the exception its evident that you are trying to include a value to an immutable dictionary.

Unwrap the values one at a time and since you are going to edit them always make a mutableCopy

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSMutableDictionary *clothingAssets=[[defaults dictionaryForKey:@"ClothingAssets"] mutableCopy];

NSMutableArray *clothingStores      = [clothingAssets[@"ClothingStore"] mutableCopy];
NSMutableDictionary *clothingStore  = [clothingStores[temp_Store] mutableCopy];

NSMutableDictionary *assets         = [clothingStore[@"Assets"]mutableCopy];

NSString *assetTypesKey             = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",temp_AssetType];
NSMutableArray *assetTypes          = [assets[assetTypesKey]mutableCopy];
NSMutableDictionary *assetType      = [assetTypes[i] mutableCopy];

//Value is set
assetType[@"isLock"] = @"YES";

//Now you need to update the values back to the top most level
[assetTypes replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:assetType];
assets[assetTypesKey] = assetTypes ;
clothingStore[@"Assets"] = assets;
[clothingStores replaceObjectAtIndex:temp_Store withObject:clothingStore];
clothingAssets[@"ClothingStore"] = clothingStores;

[defaults setObject:clothingAssets forKey:@"ClothingAssets"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Comment: mutableCopy is indeed the key answer here. This is a standard plist gotcha.

Answer (score 0):

Nested message sends aside, this is actually rather straightforward. When you see that error, it means you're trying to mutate an immutable object. The runtime throws a tantrum when you try to do that. Instead, do this:

```
ClothingAssets=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"ClothingAssets"];
NSDictionary *clothingStore = [ClothingAssets objectForKey:@"ClothingStore"];
NSArray *assets = [clothingStore objectForKey:@"Assets"];
NSDictionary *subAsset = [assets objectAtIndex: temp_Store];
NSArray *subAssetArray = [subAsset objectForKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",temp_AssetType];

// At this point I'm afraid I run out of creative ways to describe your storage hierarchy:
NSDictionary *subAssetArraySubDictionary = [subAssetArray objectAtIndex: ii];
NSMutableDictionary *mutableCopy = [subAssetArraySubDictionary mutableCopy];

// And finally, set the value:
// Beware: This uses the string YES instead of a boolean value for YES - you need to remember this
// when accessing it later.
[mutableCopy setValue: @"YES" forKey: @"isLock"];
```